# Selenium fails to open browser with "Process unexpectedly closed with status signal"

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I'm using Selenium + seleniumwire and got a bug that previously never happened. Firefox just stopped opening on MacOS. Here are the logs:

```
[2024-01-02 17:03:40,768] [INFO] Using default request storage
[2024-01-02 17:03:40,783] [INFO] Created proxy listening on ::ffff:127.0.0.1:53812
[2024-01-02 17:03:40,795] [DEBUG] Started executable: `/Users/v/p/drivers/geckodriver_mac` in a child process with pid: 7630 using 0 to output -3
[2024-01-02 17:03:41,313] [DEBUG] POST http://localhost:53806/session {"capabilities": {"firstMatch": [{}], "alwaysMatch": {"browserName": "firefox", "acceptInsecureCerts": true, "moz:debuggerAddress": true, "pageLoadStrategy": "normal", "proxy": {"proxyType": "manual", "httpProxy": "[::ffff:127.0.0.1]:53812", "sslProxy": "[::ffff:127.0.0.1]:53812"}, "moz:firefoxOptions": {"prefs": {"network.proxy.allow_hijacking_localhost": true}}}}}
[2024-01-02 17:03:41,442] [DEBUG] Remote response: status=500 | data={"value":{"error":"unknown error","message":"Process unexpectedly closed with status signal","stacktrace":""}} | headers=HTTPHeaderDict({'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'cache-control': 'no-cache', 'content-length': '110', 'date': 'Tue, 02 Jan 2024 16:03:41 GMT'})
[2024-01-02 17:03:41,443] [DEBUG] Finished Request
[2024-01-02 17:03:41,444] [DEBUG] Cleaning up /var/folders/07/gxcrb9qd76lgrt90992jdn7c0000gn/T/.seleniumwire/storage-fac3f55b-22c1-4b2a-9bbb-03d61b5dbfbd
[2024-01-02 17:03:41,455] [ERROR] [Try 1/10] Message: Process unexpectedly closed with status signal
```

Initially it worked fine and still is working on Debian linux.
I updated gecko driver, Firefox, selenium and all libraries to the last versions. It didn't help.
Any ideas on how to debug ad fix the issue?

MacOS Sonoma 14.2.1
Firefox 121.0
Geckodriver 0.33
Python 3.8.13

Answer (score 1):

Upd: Today's update for gecko driver 0.34.0 (2024-01-03) solved the issue.